# How to run a single command via ssh to WSL2

Tags: command-line, ssh, windows-11, wsl2

I'm trying to run a command from a non-Windows device that looks something like this:

```
ssh me@host 'cat file' > file
```

`host` is a Windows 11 box that is configured to SSH directly into a WSL2 shell.  I enabled this by setting a registry entry with the following admin PowerShell command:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

However, whenever I try to run this command I get this error:

```
Invalid command line argument: -c
Please use 'wsl.exe --help' to get a list of supported arguments.
```

It appears that wsl.exe uses the non-standard "-e" option instead of "-c", but how do I tell sshd to use that when I supply a command to be executed?  I can't supply it in the command line I actually pass, because then it tries to use the `-c` option so for instance something like this: `ssh -t '"C:\Program Files\WSL\wsl.exe" ...` won't work because it tries to invoke wsl.exe using the `-c` option which wsl.exe doesn't support.

This also seems to mess with my ability to use things like scp. The whole purpose of running the ssh command is to try to work around that, which in turn is caused by difficulties accessing files in WSL via the default command shell provided by ssh (for instance, if I have an ext4 drive mounted under WSL and exposed as a network drive to Windows, my ssh session can't see the files on it.

Comment: Try this command : `New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\WINDOWS\System32\bash.exe" -PropertyType String -Force`. For details see [this link](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/the-easy-way-how-to-ssh-into-bash-and-wsl2-on-windows-10-fro).

Comment: Syntax matters....`New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe" -PropertyType String -Force` is linking the `-PropertyType String -Force` to WSL.exe while `New-ItemProperty -PropertyType String -Force -Path "HKLM:SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe"` might resolve the issue of courses I suspect what your are attempting WILL not work as you are attempting to do something that is not intended to have happen. However, that would launch WSL,it would not launch a bash shell necessarly.

Comment: @harrymc I can still ssh directly after this, but when I try my "cat" command it hangs. When I look at the output file there appear to be some cursor control codes followed by "C:\Windows\system32\conhost.exe" and some more cursor control codes.

Comment: Where did you find this command? I suspect it's not [this](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/the-easy-way-how-to-ssh-into-bash-and-wsl2-on-windows-10-from-an-external-machine) since it's not using the correct path.

Comment: @Ramhound Which command? The New-ItemProperty command?

Comment: It be simpler to ssh directly into WSL, rather than into Windows. See for example [this post](https://jmmv.dev/2022/02/wsl-ssh-access.html). I can summarize it in an answer, if it works.

Comment: @Michael - The PowerShell code you are trying to execute.

Comment: @Ramhound a certain AI gave it to me... and it does work for being able to ssh directly into WSL which is all I originally asked for.  What it does not do is provide the ability to pass commands.

Comment: ChatGPT is incorrect. [Here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/the-easy-way-how-to-ssh-into-bash-and-wsl2-on-windows-10-from-an-external-machine) is the source, which ChatGPT used, to generated it's incorrect response which absolutely NOT work.  Scott Hanselman's script migt work. It is 3 years old, and WSL has changed a ton, in the last 3 years. What I can tell you is that the response you received, and the script that was generated, won't work.

Comment: @Ramhound No.  Using bash.exe as the executable results in a strange message about conhost.exe and I don't get the prompt back when I try to ssh with a specific command.

Comment: @Michael.  Please edit the question to include that you have tried this and what message you received.